# Unexpected Result from mySQL Query

Tags: mysql

My problem is I'm not getting the right output that I needed to.

I have `three tables`

**Products**

```
id  title
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
```

**Orders**

```
id  order_date
1   01-20-2016
2   02-27-2016
3   03-29-2016
```

**Order_details**

```
id  prod_id   order_id  quantity
1   1           1           1   
2   3           1           1
3   2           2           2
4   1           2           1
5   3           2           1
6   2           3           1
7   1           3           2
```

**Not expected output**

```
title   date        Quantity
aaa     January         2
aaa     February        4
aaa     March           3
```

**Output that I'm expecting**

```
title   date        quantity
aaa     January         1
aaa     Febuary         1
aaa     March           2
bbb     January         0
bbb     Febuary         2
bbb     March           1
ccc     January         1
ccc     February        1
ccc     March           0
```

**This is my query so far.**

```
SELECT products.title, DATE_FORMAT(orders.order_date, '%M') as date, SUM(order_details.quantity) as quantity 
FROM products, orders, order_details 
WHERE products.id = order_details.product_id and orders.id = order_details.order_id
GROUP BY date
```

Can someone help me in getting the `expected output`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GROUP BY is missing the title field so only the month is being used

Try

```
GROUP BY title, date
```

Answer (score 0):

you are grouping the results only by date, so for example for January it will sum the following lines :

```
aaa     January         1
bbb     January         0
ccc     January         1
```

and the output will be

```
aaa     January         2 (sum of 1+0+1)
```

use

```
GROUP BY title, date
```